# Integrate $\iiint_E z\,dx\,dy\,dz$ in $E=\lbrace(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4, z \leq 1 \rbrace$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to integrate $\iiint_E z\,dx\,dy\,dz$ in $E=\lbrace(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4, z \leq 1 \rbrace$.

I want to split that triple integral in 3 integrals, but I don't see which the limits are.

I guess I have to do $x \leq \pm \sqrt{4-y^2-z^2}$ and integrate in $x$ between those limits (I don't know if this is correct) but then I get lost with the $y$ limits. If I let $z$ be the last variable I integrate, I suppose I can say that $z$ is between $-2$ and $1$, so that limits are easy.

What are the limits of the $y$ integral? And are the $x$ limits okay? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with cylindrical coordinates as that is the simplest here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will first tell you the easiest way which is using cylindrical coordinates.

$x^2+y^2 = r^2$ so $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4 \implies r^2 \leq 4-z^2$

So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-2}^{1} \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} r \ z \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$

Can you see why it is the simplest?

Also note that as $z$ is an odd function, its integral between $-1 \leq z \leq 1$ will be simply zero due to symmetry of the region wrt z-plane.

So integral between $-2 \leq z \leq -1$ will give you the same result. This point becomes important if you decide to use spherical coordinates for the integral.

If one is integrating for $z \leq 1$ using spherical coordinates, the integral must be split into two. In spherical coordinates,

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

At $z = 1, \rho = \sec \phi$ and to find upper bound of $\phi$, $1 = 2 \cos\phi \implies \phi = \frac{\pi}{3}$. So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/3} \int_{0}^{\sec\phi} \rho^3 \cos\phi \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta + \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \rho^3 \cos\phi \sin\phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta$

Now as I mentioned earlier, you can simply write it as one integral between $-2 \leq z \leq -1$ and I will leave the set-up of that integral as an exercise for you.

Comment: Hope you don't mind that i comment here. I was wondering how $ \,dx\,dy\,dz   = r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta $

Comment: @Fosofof in cylindrical coordinates, $x = r \cos\theta, y = r \sin\theta, z = z$. So just like in 2D polar coordinates, $dx \ dy = r \ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: One last question, why is it that it is the easiest way to use cylindrical coordinates. The body is a sphere. Maybe i have been staring too long on the problem, so it all mixes.

Comment: @Fosofof because the region is also bound by a plane ($z = 1$). Part of the region being sphere does not always mean spherical coordinates is simpler. Take a ray from the origin and change the angle that it makes with z-axis. Is the ray always bound above by the spherical surface? If yes, spherical coordinates is simpler. Take for example a cone with spherical cap. It works but here, for part of it, you are bound above by a plane and a plane is not that pleasant in spherical coordinates.

Comment: I was preparing other exams, and I left the integral behind. I was struggling with what I should do with the z ≤−1 part and this morning I went into this page and I saw your answer. I guess you are right. I was distracted with a part of the region being a sphere, but with cylindrical coordinates seems way easier, plus I only have to do one integral. Thank you and my apologies for the delay

Comment: @cookiealv that is no problem, we all have priorities. Feel free to ask any questions you may have.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) in which a Cartesian triple $(x,y,z)$ is equivalent to a spherical triple $(R,\theta,\phi)$ such that
$${
x=R\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
x=R\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z=R\cos\theta.}
$$
In this spherical coordinates, you have
$$
{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 4\iff R\le 2
\\
z\le 1 \iff R\cos\theta\le 1
\\
dxdydz=R^2\sin\theta d\theta d\phi dR.
}
$$
Now substitute and proceed to integration.

Comment: oh true, with spherical coordinates is easier. Thanks!

Comment: Are you integrating for $z \leq 1$? If yes, in spherical coordinates it will result in split integral as upper limit of $r = \sec\theta$ till you are bound by the plane $z = 1$ and after that by $r = 2$. So we will have two bounds of $\theta$.

Comment: and $dx \ dy \ dz = R^2 \sin\theta\  d\theta \ d\phi \ dR$

Comment: @MathLover, thanks. I edited the typo. Also splitting the bounds happens through splitting $\cos\theta$ to $0<\cos \theta <0.5$ and $\cos\theta<0$.

Comment: Integral gets split at $\theta = \pi/3$. Between $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/3 \ $ ($\cos\theta$ between $1$ and $0.5$) and then between $\pi/3 \leq \theta \leq \pi \ $ ($\cos\theta$ between $0.5$ and $-1$).

Answer (score 1):

I would split the integral into *two* integrals, one of length and the other of area: Since $z$ varies in the interval $[-2,1]$, the first integral should be $$\int^1_{-2}(\cdots)dz$$then if you fix $z$, you have $x^2+y^2\leqslant 4-z^2$, so you have a closed disc $B_z$ on the plane of center $(0,0)$ and radius $\sqrt{4-z^2}$, so the integral inside should be $$\iint_{B_z}zdxdy$$ so your integral is equal to $$\int^1_{-2}\iint_{B_z}zdxdydz=*$$

Now you can take $z$ out of the double integral, so $$*=\int^1_{-2}z\left(\iint_{B_z}dxdy\right)dz=\int^1_{-2}z\pi(4-z^2)dz$$ (since $\iint_{B_z}dxdy$ is noting but the area of the disc $B_z$, that is, $\pi r^2=\pi(\sqrt{4-z^2})^2=\pi(4-z^2)$)