# Determining the following triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to determine the following triple integral:

$$ \iiint_K (x^2 + y^2) \mathrm dx \mathrm d y\mathrm d z $$

The body K is given by the region that is located between

$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 2 \  $ and $ z \ge -1 \ $.

My reasoning is that it is easier to start by solving the double integral

$$ \iint_D (x^2 + y^2) \mathrm dx \mathrm dy $$

where $D$ is $ x^2 + y^2 \le \sqrt{2} $

I get that $$ \iint_D (x^2 + y^2) \mathrm dx \mathrm dy =  2\pi$$

After this, the only thing left should be to solve the single integral:

$$\int_{-1}^\sqrt{2} 2\pi \,\mathrm dz =  2\pi (\sqrt2 + 1). $$

This answer is obviously wrong.

I know how to solve it if i start off calculating a single integral instead of a double integral. But doing that forces me to split up the integral into two. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot evaluate a triple integral this way, try converting to spherical polar coordinates.

Comment: Please check my answer to this question though it is not the accepted answer. The accepted answer is not clearly explained. You can do it in cylindrical coordinates. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4143567/integrate-iiint-e-z-dx-dy-dz-in-e-lbracex-y-z-x2y2z2-leq-4-z/4143713#4143713

Comment: @MathLover I think i understand after i've read your answer. However i was thinking, is it possible to arrive at the solution by first integrating over the whole sphere and after that subtracting the integral of the body that isn't included in the original problem?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But that will require two integrals so it is easier to just calculate between $-1 \leq z \leq \sqrt2$..

Comment: @MathLover I wasn't able to tag you in the other thread, but i was wondering how $ \,dx\,dy\,dz   = r \ dr \ dz \ d\theta$. I know that it is to take into account that we changed to different coordinates, but why it is precisely that, i don't know.

Comment: @Fosofof go down to generalisation and read about the Jacobian matrix, it explains the change of coordinate system for differentials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system